# Difference between anchor link & window.location?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the link below:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController", new SearchCriteriaAffaire { Page=3, PageSize=5 }, null)'>Test1</a>
```

This links works. I received my search criteria in my action page.

Now, I have the button with javascript below:

```
<button id="buttonTest2">Test2</button>

<script language="javascript">
   $("#buttonTest2").click(function () {            
   document.location = '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController", new SearchCriteriaAffaire { Page=3, PageSize=5 }, null)';
});
</script>
```

This button doest' work. I mean, I didn't receive my search criteria in my action page and I don't know why??

It drives me crazy!

Test1 and Test2 produces exactly the same url (I check in 'view source code' by right clicking on the html page):

```
/?SortBy=None&amp;Page=3&amp;PageSize=5'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<button id="buttonTest2">Test2</button>

<script language="javascript">
   $("#buttonTest2").click(function () {            
   document.location = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MyAction","MyController", new SearchCriteriaAffaire { Page=3, PageSize=5 }, null))';
});
</script>
```

Comment: yeah! Thank you. Why do I need to use this? I cannot see the difference in 'view source code'.

Comment: in html code implicitly html encode apply so '&' replace with &amp; but not in anchor's href becoz it take url always..